# When writing for general public, is there a general guideline for selecting kanji?

Tags: word-choice, kanji, formal-nouns

After reading numerous publications, I've spotted a trend or custom on determining whether kanji is or is not used for certain words. The most obvious ones are:

**こと・事**

> …が実は犯人だったという**こと**がわかる。
>
> (haven't found a sentence which uses 事 alone yet)

**ほう・方**

> …事前に連絡した**ほう**がいいだろう。
>
> …彼の**方**が優秀である。

**とき・時**

> …を実施した**とき**、企業の声は…
>
> その**時**が来たら、また私に…

And there are other words of which, the usage of kanji is avoided. I may want to ask which is preferrable for each of the situation above, but in another question. What I want to ask here is:

### Question

Do publishers/writers employ a certain guideline/reference for selecting kanji when writing for public reading? If so, who governs the guideline? Is there a publication describing it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is from an excerpt about when to use kana instead of kanji. Since I can't really translate it well, I'll leave a lot out, so check out the [publisher's page](http://dictionary.sanseido-publ.co.jp/dicts/encyc/allknow_conv_ja/subPage3.html).

Also, I don't have much exposure but still a couple seem strange to me, like わたし and 素敵. Even the book uses 私 in its preface.

### Words that should be written with hiragana

There is the question of whether or not a word can be written using the jōyō kanji. But there are also words where, even though they can be written using the jōyō kanji, their ease of reading and how distanced the kanji's essential meaning has come [from the word] should be taken into consideration. The following is a general criterion.

#### 1. Nouns

(1)Words that can't be written with the jōyō kanji, rephrased or replaced with jōyō kanji.
　あいさつ［挨拶］(挨 and 拶 were recently added to the list, so I'm not sure of the books current stance on them)　あぐら［胡座］　あっせん［斡旋］　竹ざお［竹竿］　手ぬぐい［手拭い］
注　動植物名を学術的なものとしてとらえたときには、常用漢字で書けるものであっても、かたかなで書くことが多くなってきている（「かたかなで書く単語」参照）。

(2)Borrowed words who's foreign-feeling has faded away; no longer feel borrowed

かるた　たばこ　きせる

#### 2. 形式名詞

こと［事］　音楽を聞くことが好きだ。
　もの［物］　決して謝るものか。
　とき［時］　彼が来るときはいつも雨だ。
　ところ［所］　聞くところによると、あいつは、もうすぐ結婚するらしい。

#### 3. Pronouns

あなた［貴方］　わたし［私］　おれ［俺］　これ［此れ］　それ［其れ］　だれ［誰］　ここ［此処］　そこ［其処］　どこ［何処］　どなた［何方］

Note: You may write the following in kanji.

私（わたくし）　僕　我　君　彼　彼女　自分　何

#### 4. Verbs・補助動詞

動詞は、意味によって、漢字とひらがなを使い分けるほうが望ましい（「漢字とかなを使い分けたほうがよい単語」参照）。

#### 5. Adjectives

ありがたい［有難い］　おもしろい［面白い］　おかしい［可笑しい］　かわいい［可愛い］　すばらしい［素晴らしい］　うらやましい［羨ましい］　うれしい［嬉しい］　ゆゆしい［由々しい］　つまらない［詰まらない］

#### 6. 連体詞

ある［或］　いわゆる［所謂］　この［此の］　その［其の］　わが［我が］

#### 7. Adverbs

あえて［敢えて］　あまり［余り］　あらかじめ［予め］　いずれ［何れ］　およそ［凡そ］　かなり［可成り］　せいぜい［精精］　せっかく［折角］　ぜひ［是非］　だんだん［段段］　なお［尚］　ほとんど［殆ど］　ますます［益益］　もし［若し］　やはり［矢張り］　わずか［僅か］

Note: Words like the following are mostly written with Kanji.

案外　一概に　主に　格別　現に　強いて　徐々に　絶えず　何しろ　奮って　優に

#### 8. Conjunctives

あるいは［或いは］　および［及び］　さて［扨］　しかし［然し］　しかも［然も］　すなわち［即ち］　ただし［但し］　ところが［所が］

#### 9. Interjectives

ああ　おい　おお　へえ　もしもし

Note: To add emphasis these are written in katakana

#### 10. Postpositions

くらい［位］　ながら［乍ら］　まで［迄］　ばかり［許り］　など［等］　ほど［程］

#### 11. 助動詞

べき［可き］　ようだ［様だ］　そうだ［相だ］

#### 12. Prefixes・suffixes

お葬式　お名前　ご覧ください　ご結婚　青み　高め　子どもたち

#### 13. いわゆる当て字

すてき［素敵］　めでたい［目出度い］　とかく［兎角］　やはり［矢張り］　おくゆかしい［奥床しい］　さすが［流石］　ちょっと［一寸］　わんぱく［腕白］

### Words that use kanji or kana depending on circumstance

意味や使い方によって、漢字とかなを使い分けると、読みやすくなる単語がある。

上げる　本を棚に上げる。
　　　　本を読んであげる。
言う　意見を言う。
　　　人間という生物。
行く　町へ行く。
　　　消えていく。
入れる　口の中へ入れる。
　　　　人の意見をいれる。
上　台の上に置く。
　　ご一読のうえ、返送願います。
内　内をかためる。
　　見ているうちに、気分が悪くなった。
得る　高収入を得る。
　　　やむをえません。
限り　限りなく広がっている。
　　　命令がないかぎり、動くな。
切る　紙を切る。
　　　この紙には書ききれない。
下さる　先生が本を下さった。
　　　　はやく返してください。
来る　明日は三時に来る。
　　　ちょっと行ってくる。
事　事は重大だ。
　　食べることが趣味だ。
出す　返事を出す。
　　　動きだす。
通り　にぎやかな通り。
　　　そのとおりです。
時　時は金なり。
　　帰りついたときはだれもいなかった。
所　新しい所へ移る。
　　今、書いているところだ。
中　家の中へ入る。
　　雨のなか、ありがとうございます。
見る　映画を見る。
　　　小説を書いてみる。
持つ　ステッキを持つ。
　　　あと五年はもつ。
物　重い物を運ぶ。
　　そんなことをするものではない。

### Words written with katakana

#### 1. Foreign countries, names

アメリカ　フランス　ロシア　ベルリン　アダムズ　アリストテレス

#### 2. Loan words

アナウンサー　インフレーション　エチケット　ケーブルカー
Note: Words that have been highly assimilated into Japanese, and words who no longer feel borrowed may also be written in hiragana.
　たばこ　てんぷら　じゅばん

#### 3. Foreign currencies and units of measure

ドル　ポンド　ユーロ　メートル　リットル　ヘクトパスカル

#### 4. 擬音語・Onomonopia

カタカタ　ガチャン　ワンワン　メーメー

#### 5. 俗語・隠語

インチキ　デカ　ピンはね

#### 6. Names of plants and animals

タヌキ　キツネ　サケ　マス　タマネギ　スミレ　ヒノキ
Note: Where the idea of a plants and animal has faded, the name is used figuratively or as a result of some manufactured product, you may also write these in hiragana.

かまぼこ　こいのぼり　のり巻き　わしづかみ

Note: It's fine to write the following plant and animal names with kanji (they've have been adopted into the jōyō kanji). 漢字で書いてもよい（常用漢字表にとりあげられている）動植物名。

動物→犬　牛　馬　蚊　蚕　鯨　猿　象　鶏　猫　羊　豚　蛇　蛍
　植物→麻　稲　芋　梅　漆　菊　桑　桜　芝　杉　竹　茶　菜　松　豆　麦　桃　柳　綿
　総称として→魚　貝　木　草　鳥　虫　藻

#### 7. 「学術用語集」で決められている語

カセイソーダ　タンパク質　リン酸

#### 8. 際立たせる場合（ふつうは、ひらがなで書く）

(1)擬態語
　ニヤニヤ　ダラリ　ノッソリ
(2)感動を表す語
　アラ　オット　マア
(3)その他、意味やニュアンスを強調する場合
　交渉はヤマを迎えた。
　この人、ちょっと、ヘンです。

#### 9. To emphasize a kanji reading

「愛」の音読みは「アイ」である。

Comment: Actually, I guess the preface of the book is consistent if 私 is read わたくし

Comment: Yes, some people prefer to write わたし in hiragana and use kanji 私 only when it is read as わたくし.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: That's really interesting, I always read 私 in my head as わたし unless furigana tells me otherwise, and I always write the kanji if I'm writing. @.@ I learn something new every day

Answer (score 8):

These are called formal noun (形式名詞). Officially, they should be written in hiragana.

PDFs of `公用文における漢字使用等について（平成22年内閣訓令第１号）` can be found [here](http://www.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/pdf/kunreibesshi_h221130.pdf) or [here](http://www.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/joho/kijun/sanko/koyobun/pdf/kunrei.pdf).

A more general guideline is that closed class words or morphemes (particles, inflectional endings, formal nouns, adverbial affixes, etc.) should be written in hiragana.

Comment: Note that the nature of this announcement is different from that of, say, 常用漢字表.  公用文における漢字使用等について is exclusively about official announcements issued by the government, as its title says.  Although some people follow the guidelines described in this announcement, the announcement itself does not tell (or even suggest) people to use it for anything other than official announcements issued by the government.