# General rule for writing simple kanji as hiragana in newspaper articles sometimes?

Tags: kanji, written-language

The second line of [ＬＩＮＥのメッセージで“株”暴落！](http://www.yomiuri.co.jp/komachi/plus/hnews/20160728-OYT8T50064.html) reads:

> ハンドルネーム「やさ夫」さんが、テレビをみながらうたた寝をしていたときのことです。

why wasn't is written as:

> ハンドルネーム「やさ夫」さんが、テレビを**見**ながらうたた寝をしていた**時**のことです。

The later helps with readability. In particular, without "見", I had to do a double-take to see the word break between "みながら" and "うたた寝".

So, there must be a reason to sometimes write simple kanji as hiragana in newspapers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding 時, this 時 is a 形式名詞 which should be written in hiragana if one needs to strictly obey guidelines. In general, you have to use とき when it translates to *when*, and 時 when it translates to *time*. You don't have to worry too much in casual writings.

See: [When writing for general public, is there a general guideline for selecting kanji?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3733/5010)

Regarding 見, I believe this should have been written in kanji. This article looks fairly casual even though it's in yomiuri.co.jp (it's essentially a copy-and-paste from a net forum), so perhaps it was not proofread seriously.