# Why is 今年 written in hiragana in this NHK news article?

Tags: word-choice, kanji, hiragana

[Article in question](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20191007/k10012115621000.html?utm_int=news-culture_contents_list-items_009)

(Note that it's not NHK easy news, but the regular nhk news)

> **ことし**のノーベル賞の受賞者の発表が７日から始まり、日本人としては**去年**、医学・生理学賞を受賞した京都大学特別教授の本庶佑さんに続き、アメリカ国籍を取得した人を含め27人目の受賞者がでるか注目されます。

I thought at first it was a weird one-off thing, but actually ことし is used consistently in the rest of the article.

> **ことし**の受賞者の発表は....

[...]

> 文学賞は去年、選考を行うスウェーデン・アカデミーのスキャンダルで発表が見送られたため、**ことし**は２年分の受賞者が発表されます。

I've read a few answers regarding the use of hiragana, especially this one :

[When writing for general public, is there a general guideline for selecting kanji?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3733/when-writing-for-general-public-is-there-a-general-guideline-for-selecting-kanj/3737#3737)

But 今年 doesn't seem to fit into any of those categories and anyway 去年 is used in the same article...

Comment: Thanks naruto. I missed the other answer during my search, it's indeed a duplicate of it.