# What does もの stand for here?

Tags: meaning, nuances, word-usage

> 真改とは薄桜鬼の第一作を「薄桜鬼　真改」としてリメイクした**もの**です。

It's from the official site.

What does もの refer to? The fact that led to the creation of the title? The title itself? Shouldn't it be こと?
Or is it もん? If so, doesn't it sound like a childish excuse rather than an explanation?

Comment: This is the website you're referring to, right? https://www.otomate.jp/smp/hakuoki/shinkai/story.php

Comment: No, this one: https://www.otomate.jp/hakuoki/shinkai/tsukikage/story/?page=shinkai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (-た)もの refers to a resultant product, i.e., something obtained by performing the preceding verb. In your sentence, もの refers to the product made by remaking, i.e., the remake version.

This is a very common and useful pattern in Japanese, but it's often hard to translate it directly using "(some)thing" into English...

- スパゲティとは小麦粉を細長い形にしてゆでたものです。
  Spaghetti is food made from flour shaped into long pieces and boiled.
- コーヒーからカフェインを抜いたものはデカフと呼ばれる。
  Coffee with caffeine removed is called decaf.
- 彼女は狐が姿を変えたものだ。
  She is a fox in disguise.
- この絵は有名な画家がクレヨンを用いたものだ。
  This painting was drawn by a famous artist using crayons.
- 真改とは薄桜鬼の第一作を「薄桜鬼 真改」としてリメイクしたものです。
  "Shin Kai" refers to *Hakuōki Shin Kai*, the remake of the first *Hakuōki*.
  (More literally: "Shink Kai" is something we made by remaking the first *Hakuōki* as *Hakuōki Shin Kai*.)

Comment: Is it 物? If I saw something like your third example, I would think it was 者 written in kana. Then, would I be wrong?

Comment: @Haragurodanshi I usually stick to hiragana following the rule "[形式名詞 should be in hiragana](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3733/5010)". But I think this is 物 in kanji even in the third example.

Comment: So, can I use this もの/物 even for living things? If it were an abstract thing, would it still be this? Or こと?

Comment: @Haragurodanshi Of course something more concrete than もの can be always used (e.g., 彼女は狐が姿を変えた高校生だ), but I somehow feel 者 is unnatural here. As a generic placeholder, もの is used even for abstract things.